# Why do the overloads of vector::insert return void?

Tags: c++, vector

```
template <class InputIterator>
    void insert ( iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last );
```

I need to insert twice into my vector, but the data is large and my vector needs to reallocate. How am I supposed to know where to insert the second time (at the same position) if the call to `insert` invalidates the iterator?

Am I supposed to do something like this:

```
int offset = position - vector.begin();
vector.insert(position, data.begin(), data.end());
vector.insert(vector.begin() + offset, moredata.begin(), moredata.end());
```

It just seems there is a better way.

Comment: `std::vector`'s iterators are random access. What are you losing by just using direct offsets? Certainly not efficiency....

Comment: Well, you could go another route and do it in one go by "chaining" iterators. Unfortunately, neiter C++ nor Boost provide such functionality, so you'll have to do it yourself. :/ Perhaps I'll write one when I'm not as busy. Shame, because I think that's the "correct" approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Er... But *you* are the only person that knows where *you* want to insert your data. How is vector supposed to know where *you* are planning to make the second insertion?

If you plan to make two consecutive insertions at the same location (just guessing), then you can convert your iterator to "reallocation-independent" form (index), and then convert it back to iterator after the first insertion.

Comment: Yes I am trying to insert at the same position, I have edited my question.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain further "you can convert your iterator to "reallocation-independent" form (index), and then convert it back to iterator after the first insertion." I don't quite understand what you mean or how to do that.

Comment: @Marlon : Random access iterators, such as `std::vector`'s, can be subtracted to yield the distance between the iterators. Thus, subtracting `std::vector<>::begin()` from an iterator yields an index. After insertion, you can use `begin() + idx` to yield a new iterator in the same position. This is STL 101 stuff ;-]

Comment: That's  what my original code was before I came here to SO. It just seems odd that vector::insert doesn't return an iterator to the same position.

Comment: @Marlon : Some other containers do because it's an efficiency savings for those containers; for `std::vector` it wouldn't be an efficiency savings, so it's omitted from the interface.

Comment: @GMan : It's in the question *now*; it wasn't when I commented.

Comment: @ildjarn: It was in the question 17 minutes before your comment. :) (Refresh! :p) It's okay, no worries.

Comment: @Marlon: an oversight, which has been remedied in C++0x.

Answer (score 3):

In C++0x, the range insertion overload of `insert` returns an iterator, just as the single-element insertion overload does.

```
template  <class  InputIterator>
    iterator  insert(const_iterator  position, 
                     InputIterator  first,  InputIterator  last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to obtain a new iterator and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a version of insert that does not return void.  Check [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/).

Comment: Reallocations in vector containers invalidate all previously obtained iterators, references and pointers, which he notes in his question.

Comment: Apologies, just re-read the question.  I like the arithmetic that you added to the question.

Comment: @Brian: Which is why you would use the new iterator, returned from `insert`, instead of any existing iterators, now invalid..

Comment: He's apparently inserting a range.  And the reference site you linked shows a `void` return type for range insertion.  But my C++0x draft shows a return type of `iterator` for all overloads.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for the follow up.  The range example in the question appears to have been added during a later edit.  The more info the better ;)